# python 'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, ipython

I is trying to use jupyter command from python, I tried uninstall and install jupyter but this is not working. i.e.

```
!jupyter nbconvert --to script test.ipynb
```

or

```
!jupyter nbextension enable
```

error is:

> 'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

I am using window 10.My juypter notebook is working however to open juypter notebook I write
`"python -m notebook"` code in terminal.
`"Jupyter notebook"` don't open anything and show the following error:

> jupyter : The term 'jupyter' is not recognized as the name of a
> cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
> of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
> correct and try again. At line:1 char:1 + jupyter notebook +rest part
> of error: + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (jupyter:String) [],
> CommandNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
> CommandNotFoundException

Comment: You should specify what operating system you're using, give more details of how you installed Jupyter, and whether you're succeeded in running a Jupyter notebook at all.

Comment: I am using window 10.My juypter notebook is working howevery to open juypter notebook I write "python -m notebook" code in terminal. "Jupyter notebook" don't open anything and show the following error:jupyter : The term 'jupyter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. 
At line:1 char:1
+ jupyter notebook
+ ~~~~~~~

Comment: rest part of error: + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (jupyter:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Clearly Jupyter does not exist in your PATH in a way that Python can find it as a command line program. What installation of Python and Jupyter did you use? Have you followed their instructions on how to invoke Jupyter once its installed? Are you following specific instructions on how to invoke the jupyter command in that way from Python?

Answer (score 1):

I spent 2 hours searching for path of that files in Windows 10 or higher. Here is mine:

```
C:\Users\**username**\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\Scripts
```

(Change your username)

Idk why this is so far, but when I added that to my PATH (you can look how to add this [here](https://windowsloop.com/how-to-add-to-windows-path/#:%7E:text=Add%20directory%20or%20program%20to%20Windows%20PATH%201,full%20directory%20path%20of%20the%20program.%20More%20items)) everything worked. Now I can run by using

```
!jupyter notebook
```

Try to search for that folder and add this to the PATH if this is correct

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Jupyter to your PATH, another thing you can do is install Anaconda.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).